# Getting unbound method error?

Tags: python

I tried to run this code below

```
class TestStaticMethod:  
    def foo():  
        print 'calling static method foo()'  

        foo = staticmethod(foo) 

class TestClassMethod:  
    def foo(cls):  
        print 'calling class method foo()'  
        print 'foo() is part of class: ', cls.__name__  

    foo = classmethod(foo)
```

After I ran this with the code below

```
tsm = TestStaticMethod()
TestStaticMethod.foo()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>  
    TestStaticMethod.foo()  
TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with TestStaticMethod instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

```
tsm.foo()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>  
    ts.foo()  
TypeError: foo() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I really don't get why I'm getting the unbound method. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your indentation seems to be broken. Fixing it should fix the problem. (Also, you should go read about decorator syntax.)

Comment: Yes i got the broke point, thanks for the suggestion.And yes using decorator it's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You shall try the below code by dedenting the `foo` variable from class `TestStaticMethod`

```
class TestStaticMethod:
    def foo():
        print 'calling static method foo()'
    foo = staticmethod(foo)


tsm = TestStaticMethod()
tsm.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not indent

> foo = staticmethod(function_name)

in function(foo) itself,

Instead give this a try:

```
class TestStaticMethod:  
    def foo():  
        print 'calling static method foo()'  
    foo = staticmethod(foo)
```

or

```
class TestStaticMethod:  
    @staticmethod
    def foo():  
        print 'calling static method foo()'
```

Both above solutions will work

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you.